# How to set current date of datepicker to textbox value

Tags: php, javascript, datepicker

I am developing application for hotel booking..
I have used 2 datepickers for selecting check-in & check-out date..

But now i want my first date-picker's current value to be shown on that textbox by default & another textbox of second datepicker to be filled by date of 2 days after...

Just like these datepickers....

http://www.yatra.com/hotels.html

can anyone suggest me,how to do this??

I have used same datepickers as shown in link..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Depend on your date-picker lib, which one is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a date like this (if the datepicker is initialized)

```
$('#your-selector')
    .datepicker('setDate',new Date());
```

of a uninitialized datepicker use:

```
$('#your-selector')
    .datepicker().datepicker('setDate',new Date());
```

to create a date 2 days before... make this:

```
var today = new Date();
var twoDaysBefore = new Date();
twoDaysBefore.setDate(today.getDate()-2);
```

and set the date

```
$('#your-selector')
    .datepicker('setDate', twoDaysBefore);
```

you can create a function if you need this algorithm more times:

```
var getDate = function(daysDelta) {
    var d = new Date();
    (d.setDate(d.getDate()+daysDelta));
    return  d;
}

console.log(getDate(-3))
```

without jQuery (thanks), format your date object like this:

```
var d = getDate(-2);
var yyyy = d.getFullYear().toString();
var mm = (d.getMonth()+1).toString();
var dd  = d.getDate().toString();
var dateAsString =  yyyy + "-" + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + "-" + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+1);
document.getElementById('id').setAttribute('value', dateAsString);
```

Comment: he didn't notice that JQuery is used.

Answer (score 0):

If datepicker1 is your datepickers id and datepicker2 is the second one then

```
$("#datepicker1").val(new date());

var date2 = $('datepicker1').datepicker('getDate', '+2d'); 
date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1); 

$("#datepicker2").val(date2);
```

Comment: thanks,but i think this is static value for both datepicker,I want everyday changing with this pattern

Comment: he didn't notice that JQuery is used.

Answer (score 0):

Todays Date

```
$("#date_pick").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Date of 2 days after

```
var nextDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
$("#date_pick2").datepicker('setDate', nextDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 $('first').datepicker({

 onSelect: function(){
 var start = $('first').val();

 var date = new Date(start);
 var d = date.getDate();
 var m = date.getMonth();
 var y = date.getFullYear();
 var edate= new Date(y, m, d+2);

 $('second').val(edate);
}
});
```